# NSD File sharing android

Tags: android, image, send, android-wifi, nsd

I am building an app using NSD api from google to share pictures between two android devices.
I imported the NSDchat example from android website and managed to implement it in my app and I successfully created a connection between two android devices on the same wifi network and was able to send a string . However I want to send pictures from one device to another.
i managed to open the camera on a surface view and take pictures and save them to the phone but couldn't send it to the other device.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to send picture is to convert it to bytes array and then transmit it over streams(OutputStream  to read and InputStream to write bytes).